What is causing the program to run once but not continuously?
I am experimenting with multiprocessing.ThreadPool and Queues, and am getting some odd behaviour that I dont understand. The program runs through once but does not continuously do so as it should.
At first I thought it was a pycharm issue, so I started by updating pycharm and my os that had no luck.Then I changed the run configuration by adding the option "Run with Python Console" but that just runs through once. I also tried "Adding To Process" as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/46440286/28215801 . Then I tried adding a Lock to the code thinking it was a race issue but that also hasnt solved the issue.
The only thing that works is running the program in debug and then stepping through the code, this gets the behaviour I want but is impractical.
worker_core.py
#import common_imports as ci

import logging
from queue import Queue, Empty
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from multiprocessing import Event
from threading import Lock
import time

class MultithreadedPoolAndQueue:
    def __init__(self, available_modules):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("Test_Program.MultithreadedPoolAndQueue")
        self.available_modules = available_modules
        self.logger.info("Multithreaded Pool and Queue Management Initialised")
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.pool = ThreadPool(processes=len(self.available_modules))
        self.all_tasks_completed = Event()
        self.lockymclockface = Lock()

    def unpack_results(self,results):
        filtered_results = []
        for key, val in results.items():
            if isinstance(val, list):
                for item in val:
                    filtered_results.append({key: item})
            else:
                filtered_results.append({key: val})

        return filtered_results

    def fill_queue(self, data):
        for d in data:
            # Each data will be {DATA_TYPE: Data}
            self.queue.put(d)

    def parse_results(self, results):
        """
        This function will need the filtered results.
        It will put the data onto the queue like this: {DATA_TYPE: Data}


        :param results:
        :return:
        """
        self.logger.info(f"Entering parse_results with: {results}")
        if results is None:
            pass

        else:
            unpacked_results = self.unpack_results(results)

            for result in unpacked_results:
                self.logger.info(f"Result added: {result}")
                self.queue.put(result)


    def error_call(self,e):
        self.logger.error(e)
        pass

    def thread_worker(self):
        max_check_count = 10
        check = 0
        loop_around = 0

        while self.queue.empty() is False or loop_around < 2 and check < max_check_count:
            try:

                    item = self.queue.get_nowait()

                    # Assuming item is in the format {data_type: data}
                    data_type = next(iter(item))  # Get the first (and only) key from the dictionary
                    query = item[data_type]

                    # Then for each module in available modules, apply an asynchronous system
                    for module in self.available_modules:
                        for module_name, module_class in module.items():
                            # Check if the module can handle this data type
                            if data_type in module_class.accepted_data:
                                with self.lockymclockface:
                                    module_instance = module_class()
                                    self.pool.apply_async(module_instance.event,args=(query, data_type),callback=self.parse_results,error_callback=self.error_call)

                    loop_around = 0
                    check = 0  # Reset check counter on successful item processing

            except Empty:
                # If the queue is empty, wait for a short time before checking again
                time.sleep(0.1)
                check += 1
                loop_around += 1

            except Exception as e:
                self.logger.exception(e)
                loop_around += 1

        # Wait for all async tasks to complete
        self.pool.close()
        self.pool.join()
        self.all_tasks_completed.set()

    def wait_for_completion(self):
        self.all_tasks_completed.wait()
        self.logger.info(f"Queue item: {self.queue.get()}")
        self.logger.info("All tasks have been completed.")



How I am using it:
threaded_core = worker_core.MultithreadedPoolAndQueue(self.available_modules)
threaded_core.fill_queue(self.targets)
threaded_core.thread_worker()
threaded_core.wait_for_completion()

Complete project files can be found at: https://pastebin.com/u/cantcode4sh
NOTE: The modules folder is meant to be in the consumer_producer folder. When running don't forget to add the path to the config.ini file, and add the config.ini file to the Test_Program.py when running.

NameError: name 'worker_core' is not defined that's the error we get ... when we run that code

you need to make a [mcve] of the problem

@AhmedAEK added the pastebin folder, thank you for looking at my problem.

Your example works fine and exits successfully, the only bug i see is that self.all_tasks_completed.set() is not wrapped in a try-finally (or a with block) , so if an exception happens at an unexpected time you will be stuck waiting on an event that never happens

Also since you are calling sys.exit it will terminate your interactive session .... which i think is what's causing your confusion
